How to replace "variables" in docx in Apache POI Java
I am writing a method that replaces text in docx document using apache POI. In the document itself there are x number of "variables" marked with "<<>>". So for example doc midth look something like that: "On the << date >>, person << Name >> does << Task >>.". The point of the method is to get XWPFParagraph and Map<String, String> variableValues, and to go throw the runs of the paragraph and replace where it finds the key of the variableValues (so tha is the hardcoded into the document) with the value of the key.
private void replaceTextInParagraph(XWPFParagraph paragraph, Map<String, String> variableValues) {
        List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();
        StringBuilder paragraphText = new StringBuilder();

        // Step 1: Gather all text from the paragraph
        for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
            String text = run.getText(0);
            if (text != null) {
                paragraphText.append(text);
            }
        }

        // Step 2: Perform replacements on the complete text
        String replacedText = paragraphText.toString();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : variableValues.entrySet()) {
            replacedText = replacedText.replace("<<" + entry.getKey() + ">>", entry.getValue());
        }


        // Step 3: Clear all existing runs
        for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
            run.setText("", 0);
        }

        // Step 4: Add the replaced text back to the paragraph
        if (!replacedText.isEmpty()) {
            XWPFRun newRun = paragraph.createRun();
            newRun.setText(replacedText);
        }
    }

This is the latest iteration of the code, but here there is a fundamental problem. It messes a lot with the  styling of the code. It chances the font (for example from 11 to 10, but not consistently in the entire file), also if one variable is bolded so that meant this: <>, then the value of the variable must be bolded too. But in practice had mixed solutions, in the same doc we had one paragraph totally bolded and the other was the exact oposite and wasn't bolded, even tho, both paragraph were with just a few bolded variables.
And these are the method I am using to go through the document.
    public void replaceVariables(XWPFDocument document, Map<String, String> variableValues) {
        for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
            replaceTextInParagraph(paragraph, variableValues);
        }
        for (XWPFHeader header : document.getHeaderList()) {
            for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : header.getParagraphs()) {
                replaceTextInParagraph(paragraph, variableValues);
            }
            processTables(header.getTables(), variableValues);
        }
        for (XWPFFooter footer : document.getFooterList()) {
            for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : footer.getParagraphs()) {
                replaceTextInParagraph(paragraph, variableValues);
            }
            processTables(footer.getTables(), variableValues);
        }
        processTables(document.getTables(), variableValues);
    }
    private void processTables(List<XWPFTable> tables, Map<String, String> variableValues) {
        for (XWPFTable table : tables) {
            for (XWPFTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
                for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
                    for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : cell.getParagraphs()) {
                        replaceTextInParagraph(paragraph, variableValues);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

I am also giving you two of the old versions of the code, to see what i have tried in the past. The last solution I gave is the closest i have been to the program working properly.
    private void replaceTextInParagraph(XWPFParagraph paragraph, Map<String, String> variableValues) {
        List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();
//        List<XWPFRun> newRuns = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder paragraphText = new StringBuilder();

        for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
//            XWPFRun newRun = run;
//            newRun.setText("", 0);
//            newRuns.add(newRun);

            String text = run.getText(0);
            if (text != null) {
                paragraphText.append(text);
            }
        }

        String replacedText = paragraphText.toString();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : variableValues.entrySet()) {
            replacedText = replacedText.replace("<<" + entry.getKey() + ">>", entry.getValue());
        }

//        while (!paragraph.getRuns().isEmpty()) {
//            paragraph.removeRun(0);
//        }
        String [] textParts = replacedText.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < runs.size(); i++) {
            int j = 0;
            runs.get(i).setText(textParts[j], 0);

            paragraph.addRun(runs.get(i));
        }
//
//        XWPFRun newRun = paragraph.createRun();
//        newRun.setText(replacedText);
    }

    private void replaceTextInParagraph(XWPFParagraph paragraph, Map<String, String> variableValues) {
        StringBuilder paragraphText = new StringBuilder();
        List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();

        // First, get the entire text of the paragraph
        for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
            String text = run.getText(0);
            if (text != null) {
                paragraphText.append(text);
            }
        }

        // Perform the replacement on the entire paragraph text
        String replacedText = paragraphText.toString();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : variableValues.entrySet()) {
            replacedText = replacedText.replace("<<" + entry.getKey() + ">>", entry.getValue());
        }

        // Split the replaced text back into runs
        int currentIndex = 0;
        for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
            String text = run.getText(0);
            if (text != null) {
                int remainingLength = replacedText.length() - currentIndex; // Calculate remaining length in the replaced text
                String subText;

                if (text.length() <= remainingLength) {
                    // Safe to use the entire length of the run
                    subText = replacedText.substring(currentIndex, currentIndex + text.length());
                } else {
                    // Limit the length to the remaining text length
                    subText = replacedText.substring(currentIndex);
                }

                run.setText(subText, 0);  // Update text in each run
                currentIndex += subText.length();
            }
        }
    }

I cannot stress this enough, the styling of the document must remain consistent. So if you try to remove all the runs and create new once, you will lose all the images in the document, and if you try to replace the new text in the old runs, you will find text that is longer, so it will cut the end of for example a name or the date. So please, i need help with this, I do not know how to fix it and at this point have tried everything.
P.S. I know I can switch to Bookmarks, but before that I am trying to see if it is possible with the simple text.

Try to process the underlying XWPFRuns instead of just the Paragraphs etc if you want to keep the styling? Though be aware that your variable text may end up spanning multiple Runs if Word is feeling unhelpful...

See https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user%3a3915431%20textsegment&searchOn=3

The following logic is unnecessarily going through the text for every variable
String replacedText = paragraphText.toString();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : variableValues.entrySet()) {
  replacedText = replacedText.replace("<<" + entry.getKey() + ">>", entry.getValue());
}

This will get slower and slower the more variables you add.
You could achieve the same result with a single pass over the text using a regular expression
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<<([^>]+)>>");
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer ();
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(paragraphText.toString());
while (matcher.find()) {
    String key = matcher.group(1);
    String replacement = variableValues.containsKey(key) ? variableValues.get(key) : matcher.group(0);
    matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, replacement);
}
matcher.appendTail(buffer);
String replacedText = buffer.toString();


Thank you for the comment! I am aware that the replacing part is not the most efficient code. But my problem is with the apache POI functionality of the method :)

A .docx file is just a zip file containing

an xml file with the text plus markup for the document
other resources (eg images) referenced by the xml file

You can try this yourself by renaming myfile.docx to myfile.zip and opening it (eg with winzip).
A simple solution might be to do the replacements without using apache poi

Unzip the .docx
Find and replace the <<variables>> in the xml
Zip it back up again
Save the result as a .docx

You might find that <<x>> is represented as &lt;&lt;x&gt;&gt; in the xml
I feel this solution might be much cleaner / simpler than using apache poi

You might find Dear <<first_name>> text... as ...<w:r><w:t>Dear &lt;&lt;</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>first_name</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>&gt;&gt; </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>text...</w:t></w:r>... in XML. What then?

I think it's safe to expect formatting to apply to the whole variable, and not part of it. So your example above would be "illegal" (and would remain as is). I'd expect Dear <w:r><w:t>&lt;&lt;first_name&lt;&lt;</w:t></w:r>... to be replaced

"Expect" and "actually done by Microsoft Word" often differ....

Ah... I don't claim to be an expert on the .docx markup. Can ms word really put random tags in the middle of a text block that has the same formatting?

It should not be random, but formatting is not the only reason to split text into different text runs. It is also used to mark spell check and grammar check, to mark spacing, to mark last changes in text, to mark ... else things a default user not is aware of ... (so after all it is random ;-)).

hmm... thanks for the info. That would certainly add a level of difficulty to the vanilla java/xml based approach
